# How does protocol overhead affect differently between me and my ISP?

Tags: networking, router, performance, internet, routing

What is protocol overhead and how does it affect the router (and modem) in my house differently from my ISP's network; doesn't the same overhead need to travel through both why do I need a port with more bandwidth in my router than my ISP provides me with?

I have subscribed to gigabit FTTH speeds (probably unnecessary luxury but I digress) and I have been advised not to rely on my ISP's equipment (the subscription includes a commodate to provide me with the equipment).

Comment: Protocol overhead refers to the resource commitment required to process traffic using a given network protocol, without regard to the actual data payload of the traffic. the resources can include bandwidth, memory, CPU, etc. This is not a common metric, and I've only ever seen it used in cases where many many small connections are occurring within an app, so the ratio of protocol data to actual application data is large.  Not sure what this has to do with your ISP or your router ports though. not really related. so Why do you ask?

Comment: @FrankThomas Because I have beed adviced not to rely on "freebies" if I want luxury I need to pay for it. I.e Actually buy better equipment out of pocket instead of staying with the "gratuitous/free" commodate.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos Sounds like someone is messing around with you. In general, the ISPs equipment is the best stuff to use. The only caveat I would ever make is to not use ISP equipment as a router. Just use the equipment as a modem and use your own router. Not because of overhead, but because ISP routers are just not great in general: Bad UX and bad options. Otherwise, distrusting ISP equipment is really nonsense some “elite” hardware tweakers would say to bully and mess around with others and not much else.

Comment: While ISPs tend to have "cheaper" hardware, for specialised situations they are often better optimised for the ISP network and/or their support services. Third-party harware tends to be more generic or more expensive for the same level of performance or support, but can have more specific features included in that price. You may well be paying for more bells and whistles but if you don't use those extra features all you did was pay more, and potentially paid twice, once for the ISP hardware which is included in their price and then again for another box doing the same job.

Answer (score 0):

> doesn't the same overhead need to travel through both why do I need a port with more bandwidth in my router than my ISP provides me with?

Most of it does travel all the way, yes – the IP and TCP (layers 3/4) overhead remains the same all the way through. And when it comes to lower layers (L1/L2), your Ethernet-based LAN likely has *less* protocol overhead than the WAN connection (GPON and VDSL both add more overhead below Ethernet) or the ISP's internal network (which might carry several nested VLAN tags).

However, it sounds like your ISP's plan *accounts for* the typical overhead of a TCP download (which might be as much as 6%). For example, if you're paying for a "100 Mbps" plan, you're probably expecting to download just the *real* data at 100 Mbps, so the ISP instead provides you with approx. **105** Mbps of "raw" bandwidth – the extra ~5% would be for the overhead (TCP headers, IP headers, L2 headers, etc).

I'm not entirely sure whether ISPs really do this, but I have been told that this is the case several times.

*(Note: 6% is approximate, based on a 1518-byte Ethernet frame carrying 1440 bytes of useful data and 78 bytes of L2/L3/L4 overhead.)*

So an "100 Mbps" ISP plan likely gives you enough extra bandwidth to transfer 100 Mbps of actual data. But on the other hand, an "100 Mbps" Ethernet port *doesn't* do that – it's exactly 100 Mbps for everything, period, so if you account for ~5% of per-packet overhead, you're left with only a 95 Mbps "download speed".

(A "gigabit" connection might be different though, as you might literally be getting a raw 1 Gbps fiber-Ethernet line without any additional ISP-imposed limits – the only hard limit would be the physical connection itself. In that situation, a faster LAN-side port wouldn't help, as the 1 Gbps WAN connection would be the bottleneck anyway.)

---

> I have beed adviced not to rely on "freebies" if I want luxury I need to pay for it. I.e Actually buy better equipment out of pocket instead of staying with the "gratuitous/free" commodate.

*Some* ISPs do provide good equipment, so try it out first and read reviews for that specific model before rushing to replace it. (Probably depends on what country you're in, and what kind of WAN connection it is.)

Comment: How do I know whether my ISP's plan accounts for overhead (and all the extra frills needed so I get my packet safe) how do I know if the "guaranteed" 100 Mbps are net or gross? When a speedtest (ookla for example) measures my speed does it count the ovearhead or does it "open" the packet (does a speedtest measure the net speed or the gross speed). If the guaranteed speed is the net speed (probably then what is transfered is more so more has to pass through the port too so as to get to my computer safe) then it is logical that I would need a "wider" port (more bandwidth).

Comment: Can't answer that for all ISPs – but the one here offers 100Mbps/300M/1Gbps FTTH plans; the 1G offer (and *only* the 1G offer) has a footnote saying "actual speed will be lower as it is limited by physical line capabilities". This implies they know that if the customer pays for X Mbps they expect to see X Mbps.

Comment: Similarly, I would expect online speedtests to show net i.e. "useful" speed – one reason being that this is the measurement relevant to most users (they want know how fast they can download a file), and the other reason is that online tests *wouldn't be able to* measure overhead; they don't know what configuration you're using (e.g. they don't know whether the MTU is lower due to PPPoE or ADSL, etc) and the test program more or less just invokes a few large HTTP requests and measures the time spent, so all it knows is how much data was delivered via HTTP but doesn't know how it got there.

Comment: "the one here offers 100Mbps/300M/1Gbps FTTH plans" what do you mean here? Do you somehow know me or at least where I come from?

Answer (score 0):

Protocol overhead in computer networking refers to the information that
must be sent with the actual data being routed through the network
toward a destination.
The information is always stored at the start of the packet and is
called a header.

Data is divided into packets for transmission.
A packet contains the actual data that is being transmitted, along with
the information that the receiving application or device requires to
understand it. When routed through the Internet, a packet might be wrapped
inside another packet with a network protocol that helps to steer the
information through several nodes to reach the target location,
which is not pertinent to the data being sent and is considered
protocol overhead.

The TCP header is typically 72 bytes for Ethernet.
Wi-Fi packets have larger protocol overhead, because of more stringent
security constraints.

As you have subscribed to gigabit FTTH, the ISP's router must be of
good enough quality to support this speed. You may of course buy
a better-quality router yourself, but there is no guarantee that this
will result in better performance.
It certainly cannot change anything regarding protocol overhead,
which will stay the same no matter which router you're using.

If you have several Wi-Fi devices that do heavy work concurrently,
this may perhaps justify buying a better router. But you may get the
same improvement by chaining your router to that of the ISP.

In conclusion, as long as you have no problem with the router supplied
by the ISP, there is no need to invest. If you decide to buy a router,
it should be of better quality (and costlier). Ensure you can return it
if you don't see any improvement.